# how is it more efficient to use final/const instead of var?

Tags: dart

final/const are nice to keep a variable's value from changing, but is it more efficient to use than using var to declare the variable? I wasn't able to find if i gain any efficiency by using final/const over using var.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the following argument "I like the convenience of var, to not have to specify the datatype". You don't need to specify the type for either `const` or `final` if Dart can detect the type automatically like `var`.

Comment: `const` allows auto type detection like `const name='test';` is same as `var name='test';` but with the added benefit of it being compile-time constant. Same things goes for `final`.

Comment: thanks @julemand101, as i didn't know that. i'll update the q to leave that part out.

Comment: A const value can be entirely replaced by its value in any referencing occurences at compile time. Thus it might be a bit faster, if you are doing e.g. machine learning. Thinking of programming as an iterative process, it always is more efficient to write const wherever you can, since it is much cleaner and self explaining.

Comment: @atmin could you elaborate as an answer to the question about how const is more efficient for performance of the application after it's compiled? i agree with you that it's more self explaining. i just wanted to focus this question on the performance aspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let me try to explain.

```
class Foo {
    var bar = 4;
    function doSomething() {
         return 3 + bar;
    }
}
```

Must compute an addition everytime doSomething is called at runtime, because "bar" might change. If bar is final, the compiler can compute at compiletime. After all the remaining is something like:

```
class Foo {
    // compiler erased "bar" and substituted any occurence by the value
    function doSomething() {
        return 7; // nothing to be computed at runtime
    }
}
```

Note: most compilers detect a privat var as const, if it is never changed within its scope. But if the field is public, the compiler still won't know.